# VBScript Microsoft.XMLDOM get xml with Hebrew characters

Tags: xml, unicode, vbscript

I need to get the contents of a XML in vbsrcript using Microsoft.XMLDOM which works fine, the problem is that some of the contents of the XML are in Hebrew, which returns question marks instead of the Hebrew characters

this is my code:

```
Function readXML(url)   'Reads XML and returns the xmldom document

    if IsNull(XMLParser) Then
        Set XMLParser = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")           'XML object for loading and parsing
        XMLParser.async = false
    End If

    dim pi
    set pi = XMLParser.createProcessingInstruction("xml", " version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'")
    XMLParser.appendChild(pi)

     if XMLParser.Load(baseURL & url) then
         Set readXML = XMLParser.documentElement
          msgbox readXML.XML
     Else
         Msgbox "Error loading '" & url & "' data from Sport5.co.il " & chr(13) & "Please check connectivity",48
         readXML = null
     end if

End Function

Sub loadLeague(Sender)
    Dim leagueDocRoot
    set leagueDocRoot =  readXML("495")

    dim LeagueName


    LeagueName = leagueDocRoot.selectSingleNode("Liga").selectSingleNode("Name").text

    txtHeadline.Text = leagueName


End sub
```

If I do the revers action, and post the data, the word שלום appears as:
[image]
How can I encode the xml data received so that I can display it correctly?

TIA

Comment: Does the original XML document specify its own encoding?

Comment: yes, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>